# PHPBB verification email to user not working

Tags: phpbb

I am using PHPBB. I want new users to receive a verification email when they register but it is not working.

**My settings**:

- I am using version 3.1.4.
- Enable board-wide emails: Enabled
- Email function name: Mail
- Contact email address: My email address on my host
- Use SMTP server for email: No

When I send a 'mass email' it is received so I know the email address and facility works.

No error log issues to report.

I cannot find a solution for this anywhere.

Would appreicate some help.

Thanks

Comment: did you look at the mail server's logs to see what happened when (if?) php handed over the email? PHP  basically does the equivalent of taking an envelope and walking it down to the street corner and tosses it into a mailbox. after that, php's done.

Comment: No, how do I find my mail server logs?

Comment: /var/log/maillog, usually. depends on your platform and particular smtp server.

Comment: Thanks, I am a novice so no idea where to find those files. Do I look on my host server?

Comment: I fixed the problem by using SMPT. Contacted my host who provided me with my SMPT server name. Thanks anyway